# How do you answer the questions like "What is[are]" + noun(s)?

Tags: sentence-choice

How do you reply to the questions like...

"What is one good example of modern Beijing?"

Can I either reply with

A. "The National stadium is. "

or

B. "It's The National stadium."?

Answer (score 1):

It can't be B. since "it's" in B. implies that the original question was something like

> What is the **only** good example of modern Beijing.

A. works. It is understandable, but I would also consider

> 1. The National stadium.
> 2. The National stadium is a good one.
> 3. The National stadium is a good example.
> 4. The National stadium is a good example of modern Beijing.

Answer (score 0):

Typically in informal speech we would simply reply *The National Stadium*, as people normally don't speak in complete sentences.

If you're speaking or writing formally, then 'A' works, but if you want to be super formal than it would be more like this:

> The National Stadium is one [good example of Modern Beijing].

It works with or without the words in brackets. That's a style choice.

Answer (score 0):

Informally, you can get away with just saying `The National stadium`, but formally it must agree with the question's verb usage.

> What animal can run 500 miles per hour?
>
> A robotic cheetah can run 500 miles per hour.

See how the answer follows the same pattern as the question?

> How many people play guitar?
>
> 5 people play guitar.

Since we already know the verb used in the question though, it can be omitted because the verb is in context now.

> What time is it?
>
> 7 o'clock.

instead of

> The time is 7 o'clock.